# pandoc error: [WARNING] Could not parse YAML metadata: Unexpected 'd'

Tags: templates, compiler-errors, yaml, metadata, pandoc

I am not sure why I get the following error message while converting markdown to PDF with a template:

```bash
[WARNING] Could not parse YAML metadata at line 10 column 1: Unexpected 'd'
```

Here is the command I use to build the document:

```bash
pandoc --template eisvogel -o output.pdf input.md
```

Here is the markdown file:

```markdown
---
titlepage: true
title: Some title
author: [Author]
date: "2022-11-25"
colorlinks: true
disable-header-and-footer: true
---

# Quick Introduction 
A famous guy once said:
```

The error occurs when I add the `disable-header-and-footer: true`. If this line is not here, then the Pandoc processes the document.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The space after the colon in the offending line is not a normal (ASCII) space but the Unicode character U+202F, "Narrow Non-Break Space". The YAML parser doesn't see a key-value pair but a single word because of that. Replace it with an ASCII space and everything should work.

Comment: Thank you very much! How did you figure out? Like what tool?

Comment: It's not the first time I've seen Unicode chars cause problems like this, so I knew what to look for. I'm using Emacs as my editor, which has a keyboard shortcut `C-x =` to get more info about a character, which made it easy to identify the problematic char.